# Beginner guide to OpenGLES on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

Does anyone know a good beginners guide to using OpenGLES on the iPhone? I have found some but they all require assumed knowledge which I don't have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simon Maurice has some great tutorials on the very first steps. Take a look: http://www.cocoachina.com/wiki/index.php?title=Category%3aSimon_Maurice_iPhone_OpenGL_ES. Do them from the beginning and you'll have a good sense of the basics.

**EDIT:**
[Backup link](http://web.me.com/smaurice/iPhone_OpenGL_ES_Blog/iPhone_OpenGL/Archive.html)
[Source code](https://github.com/mauriceatron/iPhone-OpenGL-ES-Tutorial-Series)

Comment: This is where I started. It will get you very far. +10 if I could.

Comment: Wow, I thought this question would never be answered. Wonder why that website didn't come up in a google search.

Comment: Mobile Me won't let me in, I can't access it. I would check the site for what is going on

Comment: This website no longer exists, hence it is no longer the correct answer.

Comment: Can someone edit the above to have the now correct link:
http://www.cocoachina.com/wiki/index.php?title=Category%3aSimon_Maurice_iPhone_OpenGL_ES

Comment: @jacob could you help me to find The source code for Simon Maurice tutorials?

Answer (score 9):

You need only one reference:

- http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/

Yeah, some of the documentation doesn't make a lot of sense the first time you read it, but really, read the sentence/paragraph/page again, and again.  It really does make sense, and it's very accurate.  Which is something you really can't say from tutorials.  Tutorials are almost always written by people that don't seem too fussed about leaving out important details while documentation like that is usually written by very nitpicky people that cram every little important fact into (possibly overly-complex) sentences.

Oh, and one golden tip:  Add a search function to your browser that does this:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=%s+site%3Awww.khronos.org%2Fopengles%2Fsdk%2F1.1%2Fdocs%2Fman%2F&btnI
```

(replace `%s` by whatever your browser's search term replacement string is, the above example is for Opera)

I've bound it to the `o` prefix, so whenever I need to look something up on OpenGL/ES, I just type `o glDrawElements` in the address bar and instantly get the documentation page on it.

Comment: A good resource for OpenGL, no doubt, but "you need only one"?? You really cannot started on **iPhone** dev without serious iPhone-specific help.

Comment: @LarsH: The question was specifically about OpenGL/ES.

Comment: The question was about OpenGL/ES *on the iPhone*. My point is that there is a lot of iPhone-specific stuff you have to know in order to develop for OpenGL/ES on the iPhone, and that part will not be in the OpenGL/ES SDK docs. By the way nice tip about a search function for the browser. +1

Answer (score 4):

Once again, if I may plug my own work, I have a [short writeup](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/08/05/lessons-molecules-opengl-es) on what I learned while writing [Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules) for the iPhone.  I came into this having no experience with the 3-D side of OpenGL (I had done a little 2-D hardware acceleration before), so I have a bit of a different perspective on the subject.  The [source code to Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/10/02/molecules-source-code-now-available) is available, so you might be able to learn something from poking around inside it.  I also have [written a post](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2009/01/13/opengl-es-catransform3d) on how to use Core Animation structures and functions to accelerate OpenGL ES rendering, if you want something a little more technical.

Bill Dudney has a post [here](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/wavefront_obj_files_and_learning) about how he started getting into OpenGL ES, and then a follow-on [here](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/wave_front_obj_textures_working) where he provides code for a Wavefront OBJ loader for the iPhone.

I believe that I've seen a few more good resources around Stack Overflow in various answers, so you might search around and see what else you can find here.

Answer (score 3):

For OpenGL [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) is a great tutorial. Though, it doesn't specifically cover OpenGLES, it should still be pretty helpful. Just be prepared to run into things now and again that won't work on the iphone.

Also you can get v1.1 if "The Red Book" [online](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/).

Answer (score 3):

Simon Maurice's tutorial can be found [here](http://www.cocoachina.com/wiki/index.php?title=Category:Simon_Maurice_iPhone_OpenGL_ES)

Answer (score 1):

"The Red Book" is not recommended to OpenGL/OpenGLES beginner. It is book for professionals.
The first step is should try to run downloaded simple programs or simple codes from OpenGL web sites.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good (non-Chinese) link to Simon Maurice's tutorials:
http://web.me.com/smaurice/iPhone_OpenGL_ES_Blog/iPhone_OpenGL/Archive.html

His tutorials are excellent; they're what I used to learn OpenGL ES.

Comment: Not that I have anything against Chinese, but it was visually distracting having to look at that. Good find.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to "The Red Book", another useful book -with tutorials and reference- is [OpenGL SuperBible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321498828).

Again not OpenGLES specific, but I believe it is useful to learn OpenGL features in general, then filter out the ones you don't need.