# openGL iphone tutorials

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am new bee in iPhone and wanted to work on openGL for some graphical game stuff.

Friends Please guide me in the following problems:

1. I needed some real good tutorials for openGL in iphone
2. Some tutorials in which we can get that how to move an object from one place to another so that we could animate it and read its border that is it being touched by the walls of the iphone

I have searched alot for openGL but could not find any satisfactory result.
Can u help me??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beginner guide to OpenGLES on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693613/beginner-guide-to-opengles-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did your search for? I found [this link](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html) in google, you need to read through google and read and implement to learn from them.

Another related question on SO is [Would like to learn how to use OpenGL within Objective-C, but have no idea where to start. Help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384157/would-like-to-learn-how-to-use-opengl-within-objective-c-but-have-no-idea-where)